# How to write the jest test for onclick event im salesforce lwc

Tags: jestjs, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I have below code. How can i cover in the Jest salesforce?

```
testhandle(event) {
        let testAbr = event.target.text;
        if (testAbr) {
            this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('testpasss', { detail: { type: 'specilsnumber', input: testAbr } }));
        }
    }
```

this is coming on the click of user from UI. onclick={testhandle}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do a query of the markup element on which you have added the onclick handler method, and then dispatch a custom event on that element.

**Example:**

```
element.shadowRoot.querySelector('.hasOnclick').dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('click'));
```

Make sure to add test assert in promise.resolve() to handle asynchronous DOM updates as below:

```
return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
      expect(value).toBe(expected);
});
```